# How to uninstall Bash-it?

Tags: macos, bash, bash-it

I'm not quite ready for [Bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) and would like to go back to the original CLI. Any advice on how to remove Bash-it would be awesome. Thank you.

Edit: Would love to know why I'm getting down voted so I don't make the same mistake twice.

Comment: Is the difficulty with setting your teminal's default shell, or deleting bash_it?

Comment: Deleting bash_it. When I did delete the .bash_it  folder, I got: -bash: /Users/waymond/.bash_it/bash_it.sh: No such file or directory
way-MacBook-Pro:~ waymond1$

Comment: In your /Users/waymond/.bash_it/ directory are there any other files currently?

Comment: There is not. Btw, thanks for the replies.

Comment: No worries. Can you confirm that just typing 'bash' into terminal will switch you to your bash shell, which is the default.

Comment: Yes, it goes to bash.

Comment: What are you using to delete the folder? rm -rf /Users/waymond/.bash_it ?

Comment: I did not. I deleted it a noob way but restored it. Is rm -rf /Users/waymond/.bash_it the correct way to remove it?

Comment: Down votes are probably because this is not a programming question and belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To change default shell**

System Preferences > Users & Groups > click the lock to make changes > right click (or Control click) on current user image > choose "Advanced Options"

You'll then see an option that will allow you to change the default shell. Once you reset the shell it it will change to the selected shell.

[image]

This can also be done in terminal with:

```
sudo chsh shell user
```

where shell is the shell you'd like to use (zsh,bash), and user in your case is waymond.

If you use iTerm, you'll also have further options for selecting the default shell depending on which shell you'd like to open in a new window. `Command + ,` will get you to these preferences.

I'm not familiar with bash_it specifically as a shell and haven't found any explicit removal tools. Every shell spreads it branches slightly differently so it's tricky to follow another shells removal instructions -- for example Fish: [source](http://simianzombie.com/?p=2423)

Comment: Thank you for all the help, Pippin! Helped a lot.

Comment: @Waymond Shells can be a messy hell sometimes. Onwards!

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - it does not tell the user how to uninstall Bash-it. The question is not about using a different shell...

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to do the same thing. Here's a link to removing bash-it:

https://github.com/revans/bash-it/issues/161

I found it by going to the 'Issues' tab on the GitHub repository and then selecting 'Closed' issues.

I used this list of commands from my home directory:

```
ls -1a
```

This shows the list of files in the directory, including hidden files. You should see these in the list:

- `.bash-it` (the directory you'll delete)
- `.bash_profile` (your current bash profile)
- `.bash_profile.bak` (your bash profile before installing bash-it)

```
sudo rm -rf .bash_it
```

This removes the bash-it directory. You'll be prompted for your password.

```
mv .bash_profile.bak .bash_profile
```

This overwrites the bash profile created by bash-it with your original bash profile.

```
ls -1a
```

You should now only see this file from the list above:

- `.bash_profile`

Then restart your terminal.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't actually answer the question? This is the right answer.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `sudo` to remove the `~/.bash_it` folder, unless you cloned it using `sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

Bash-it now has an uninstall script. To uninstall Bash-it, do the following:

```
# CD into the Bash-it directory
cd $BASH_IT

# Make sure you have the latest version that includes the uninstall script
git pull origin master

# Run the uninstall script
./uninstall.sh

# Remove the ~/.bash_it folder
cd ..
rm -rf $BASH_IT

# Now close this shell and open a new one
```

The uninstall script will try to restore your previous Bash configuration file (`.bash_profile` on Mac OS X, `.bashrc` on Linux).

Once you have run the uninstall script, simply open a new shell and Bash-it shouldn't be used anymore.